# React - Test if an element has 'disabled' set

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a submit button which is disabled when the form fields don't contain valid data and gets enabled when the data is correct. I am using 'useEffect' hook to check the status of the form and to update the variable which determines if `disabled` is true or false.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(...) {
            setValues({...values, isFormValid: true});
    }
}, [values]);
```

The `disabled` attribute changes its value depending on `values.isFormValid`

```
<Box m={2}>
  <Button variant="contained"
    type="submit"
    disabled={!values.isFormValid}
>
    Register
  </Button>
</Box>
```

When I run the tests, the `disabled` attribute is always present, even if the button is enabled and 'isFormValid' is true. Actually, in the DOM, the `disabled` attribute is removed, but the test fails.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Registration from './Registration';

describe('Form', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Registration />);
...............

it('should have two password fields', () => {
  expect(wrapper.find('[type="password"]').length).toEqual(2);
});

it('should enable the submit button if all the conditions are correct', () => {
    wrapper.find('[type="text"]').at(0).simulate('change', { target: { value: 'John' } });
    wrapper.find('[type="text"]').at(1).simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Doe' } });
    wrapper.find('[type="email"]').at(0).simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test@mail.com' } });
    wrapper.find('[type="password"]').at(0).simulate('change', { target: { value: '1qaz' } });
    wrapper.find('[type="password"]').at(1).simulate('change', { target: { value: '1qaz@WSX' } });
    wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.find('[type="text"]').at(0).prop('value')).toEqual('John');
    expect(wrapper.find('[type="text"]').at(1).prop('value')).toEqual('Doe');
    expect(wrapper.find('[type="email"]').at(0).prop('value')).toEqual('test@mail.com');
    expect(wrapper.find('[type="password"]').at(0).prop('value')).toEqual('1qaz');
    expect(wrapper.find('[type="password"]').at(1).prop('value')).toEqual('1qaz@WSX');

    //  TODO: After the fields are set correctly, the submit button should be enabled (disabled should be Falsy)
    // expect(wrapper.find('[type="submit"]').at(0).prop('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.find('[type="submit"]').first().getDOMNode()).toHaveProperty('disabled');
  });
```

How do I test if the `disabled` attribute still exists inside the DOM?
Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the syntax that you used, I assume that you are using `Enzyme` and `Jest` for testing.

Basically, the code:

```
expect(wrapper.find('[type="submit"]').at(0)
```

is returning a `ReactWrapper` object which is a React abstraction of your DOM Element rather than the real DOMNode itself. To test if `disabled` attribute is presented or not at the button DOM level, you can use Enzyme `getDOMNode` function.

```
expect(wrapper.find('[type="submit"]').first().getDOMNode()).toHaveProperty('disabled');
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. You are right, I am using Enzyme and Jest. I tried what you suggested, but I get this error:
`TypeError: wrapper.find(...).first(...).getDOMNode is not a function`

Comment: I think the problem is that I use `shallow` and not `mount`. If I switch to `mount`, the other assertions fail, but the last one works and vice-versa. But with `mount`, the other assertions I make won't work. I updated the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using [`jest-dom`](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom), you can use [`toBeDisabled()`](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobedisabled) matcher to test if an input element is disabled.

```js
expect(button).toBeDisabled()
```